# uding tfvc with readthedocs

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm considering setting up my own readthedocs instance. I see that they have support for Git, Mercurial, Subversion, and CVS .I do however have a couple of legacy projects which are considerable effort to move over to git sitting in TFS using TFVS.

Would it still be possible to pull in these projects using the webhook method they're talking about?

What would be the code based approach to get this to work?

Eventually I'd like to get all these opened up on Github, but thats something I still need to sell.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not support to uding tfvc with readthedocs.

It's viable to use web hooks in VSTS directly. Document from MSDN:[Web Hooks](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/integrate/service-hooks/webhooks-and-vso-vs)

However, if you want to use web hooks with TFS. You may need to use TFS plugin such as Cloudpipes. More details you can refer this link: [Integrate Team Foundation Server with Web hooks](https://www.cloudpipes.com/integrations/team-foundation-server/webhooks)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You didn't really answer my question though - I said I wanted to use webhooks. I know how to integrate them. Using this approach will I be able to get things into readthedocs? You say no but then you say it's viable. Which is it?

Comment: @Elixir, sorry, I'm not making myself clear. It's not support to uding tfvc with readthedocs. Since you have mentioned, its not support for TFVC version control. However, its available to achieve this through GIT in VSTS directly.  Since you have mentioned pull in your description. I though you were also asking the method of Git.